# Is it possible to turn a rust RocksDB iterator into a `Send + 'static` stream?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rocksdb, rust-futures

I've got a small RPC network protocol I've written, and there's a server-streaming method (very similar to gRPC style server-streaming) called `range`. The client sends start and end keys, and the server streams the values back. I'm using the [tower](https://docs.rs/tower/latest/tower/) crate as an interface in between the network protocol library and the application code that actually implements an instance of this service. I'd like to use the nice [rocksdb wrapper](https://docs.rs/rocksdb/latest/rocksdb/) that exists for Rust, but I'm running into lifetime issues. In the short term since I couldn't figure them out, I decided to use [sled](https://docs.rs/sled/latest/sled/). That worked great. However, I'd prefer to use RocksDB if I can since sled still markets itself as a beta database.

Here's a distilled version of the code involved in the problem:

```rust
use std::ops::Range;

use futures_util::{Stream, Future, future::{Ready, ready}, stream};
use rocksdb::{ReadOptions, IteratorMode, Error, DB, DBIterator};

// Service is more complicated than this, but here are the important bits
pub trait Service {
    type RequestFuture: Future<Output = Self::RequestStream>;
    type RequestStream: Stream<Item = Self::RequestItem>;
    type RequestItem;

    fn range(&self, range: Range<Vec<u8>>) -> Self::RequestFuture;
}

pub async fn network_protocol_code<T: Service>(service: T) 
where
    T::RequestStream: Send + 'static,
    T::RequestItem: Send + 'static
{
    // use service to send responses to the client
}

pub struct ExampleService {
    database: DB
}

impl Service for ExampleService {
    type RequestFuture = Ready<Self::RequestStream>;
    type RequestStream = stream::Iter<DBIterator<'static>>;
    // The actual `RequestItem` isn't actually both the key and the value, it's just a `Box<[u8]>`.
    type RequestItem = Result<(Box<[u8]>, Box<[u8]>), Error>;

    fn range(&self, range: Range<Vec<u8>>) -> Self::RequestFuture {
        let mut options = ReadOptions::default();
        options.set_iterate_range(range);
        let iterator = self.database.iterator_opt(IteratorMode::Start, options);
        let stream = stream::iter(iterator);

        ready(stream)
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
error[E0759]: `self` has an anonymous lifetime `'_` but it needs to satisfy a `'static` lifetime requirement
  --> src/lib.rs:35:38
   |
32 |     fn range(&self, range: Range<Vec<u8>>) -> Self::RequestFuture {
   |              ----- this data with an anonymous lifetime `'_`...
...
35 |         let iterator = self.database.iterator_opt(IteratorMode::Start, options);
   |                        ------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        ...is used here...
...
38 |         ready(stream)
   |         ------------- ...and is required to live as long as `'static` here
   |
note: `'static` lifetime requirement introduced by the return type
  --> src/lib.rs:32:47
   |
32 |     fn range(&self, range: Range<Vec<u8>>) -> Self::RequestFuture {
   |                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ requirement introduced by this return type
...
38 |         ready(stream)
   |         ------------- because of this returned expression

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0759`.
```

I understand to mean that it can't return a `'static` reference since the anonymous lifetime on `self` isn't `'static`, but shouldn't it be possible to return a `'static` `Stream` from an iterator like this? The first thing I tried was to get rid of that trait bound requirement in the network protocol code, but `rustc` practically dictated that the `Stream` be `Send + 'static`. This is because a new task gets spawned using `tokio::spawn` and the trait bounds there require that the `Future` is `Send` and `'static`.

I've recently read [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md), specifically [this section](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md/#2-if-t-static-then-t-must-be-valid-for-the-entire-program). I understand that to mean that the `Stream` returned here doesn't have to valid for the lifetime of the program, only until the network protocol code is finished writing it. Is it possible to get a `Send + 'static` stream out of `DBIterator` somehow? How could I go about it?

Comment: The stream still refers to the iterator, which refers to `self.database`. I think you need to `collect()` the iterator's items.

Comment: Right, that's what I've been thinking too is that the iterator refers to `self.database`. Looking in the source code it actually stores a raw pointer and uses `PhantomData` to appear to the type system that it has a type generic based on the type of `DB` you used to create it.

https://docs.rs/rocksdb/latest/src/rocksdb/db_iterator.rs.html#74

A client could potentially request hundreds of thousands of keys from the server and so allocating a buffer to hold them all contiguously is going to be a performance problem. The idea would be to use the iterator directly without buffering.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. An iterator object is not a stream you can send over the network. You should loop over the keys using the iterator and stream them out